# Erlang: running custom module

Tags: import, module, erlang, erlang-otp

Windows 7 x64, Erlang-OTP 17.
 
I wrote simple module like this:

```
-module (somequery).
-export ([fbquery/2]).

fbquery(P1,P2) ->  
    inets:start(),
    ssl:start(),
    token = "78a8shd67tyajsndweiu03hr83h19j",
    Encoded = {"Authorization","Basic " ++ base64:encode_to_string(lists:append([token,":",""]))},
    ContentType = "application/xml",
    Headers = [Encoded, {"Content-Type",ContentType}],
    Options = [{body_format,binary}],
    {ok, File}=file:read_file(P1),
    Res = httpc:request(post, {"https://datapi.com/api/xml4-8", Headers, ContentType, File}, [], Options),
    file:write_file(P2, io_lib:fwrite("~p.\n", [Res])).
```

This code working in interactive mode (werl.exe), and compiling into beam. 
The question is how use *.erl or compiled *.beam module now? How import it and run fbquery/2 method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of, you need to add the directory containing your beam with the argument `-pa Dir1 Dir2 ...`. It will add the directory to the erlang path and you will be able to type `somequery:fbquery(Arg1,Arg2)` in your shell.

Then, you can use the argument `-s module function [args..]` to launch erl with the specified function.

You can read about it in the erlang documentation for [erl](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erl.html).